# js - get client's window dimension (monitor resolution) in pixel

Tags: javascript, css, resolution

In order to design an exact web interface, I need to get client's monitor resolution with javascript whenever they access my web. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you. What's about browser's dimension? Could you help me with this?

Comment: It is in the same question mentioned above if you read all answers and comments carefully. With JQuery it's `$(window).height()` & `$(window).width()`.  For plain JS write your own like `wndsize()` here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9237810/643500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code :

```
 document.write("Available Width: " + screen.availWidth);
document.write("Available Height: " + screen.availHeight);
```

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Cannot comment but here is solution for browser height :

```
window.innerHeight/Width
```

Provided by most browsers, but not Internet Explorer 8-, and even in Internet Explorer 9+, it is not available in quirks mode.

```
document.body.clientHeight/Width
```

Provided by many browsers, including Internet Explorer.

```
document.documentElement.­clientHeight/Width
```

Provided by most DOM browsers, including Internet Explorer.

Source :
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

Answer (score 1):

For a plain vanilla answer to your question, simply look at **[screen.height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.height)** or **`screen.width.`**

e.g.

**`window.screen.height`**

**`window.screen.width`**

For browser dimensions, you can simply use **`window.height`** or **`window.width`**

If you're looking at altering design/layout based on available space, you want to look at **[media queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries)** or using a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/%E2%80%8E) or [Skel.js](http://skeljs.org/) which introduce more accessible control over **[responsiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)**.

> Media Queries is a CSS3 module allowing content rendering to adapt to
>   conditions such as screen resolution (e.g. smartphone vs. high
>   definition screen). It became a W3C recommended standard in June 2012.
>   and is a cornerstone technology of Responsive Web Design.

[...]

> Responsive Web Design (RWD) is a Web design approach aimed at crafting
>   sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and
>   navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a
>   wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer
>   monitors)